# Selecline netbook USB boot

Tags: boot, usb, ubuntu-netbook

I've a Selecline CW10Q3/873828 netbook and I want to boot and install ANY linux from USB. Digged into its BIOS, disabled quick boot and every stuff that was recommended elsewhere, USB boot is enabled and it sees the pen in "Boot from file" from it's recovery settings menu (f8) but says error message if i want to boot manually. In the boot list however it shows only Windows IA32 OS and that is all it shows. I tried to create the pen with every available software... unetbootin, rufus, yumy, linux live usb.... also tried 32bit distros but nothing works it is still invisible in boot menu. Its in FAT32 of course, every "mainstream" error is taken care of... read tons of forums but cannot get it to work and its driving me nuts!!!! tried it with dedicaed netbook distros, ubuntu, but i want elementary OS the most.... also tried to create the USB from macOS, still no luck.. (my macbook can boot it but not this piece of cr.p)

Any ideas are most welcome. Thanks

Comment: I think this a driver problem with some Atom processors, Linuxium worked for my Computestick but the author is now working on isorespin, an ISO remastering system that also builds systems for Atom processors. http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/06/customizing-ubuntu-isos-documentation.html . I think Ubuntu 16.04 Linuxium ISO is still available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proficient with Selecline BIOS, You can add some photo of its BIOS menus so we can help more.
For an ultimate solution, get the HD into another functional PC, install Linux, then replace it back into your Selecline. But be aware this may void the warranty of your PC.

Answer (score 0):

After installing a Linux version to the USB, you have to place a copy of "bootia32.efi" in the folder EFI/BOOT of the pen, next to where there already are some efi files - that will make the laptop see the USB as a bootable device...